# How do I stop wagon wheel effect when a wheel spins at low speed in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am animating a sniping wheel in blender. The wheel rotates at one revolution per second. In the view port it appears okay. But when I render the animation in cycles, it produces the wagon wheel effect. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about physics. You can change the movie fps, or you can use some motion blur to reduce the effect. You also cam change the count of details on the wheel to change the frequency,